# Android - Write file to assets folder

Tags: android

I want to download some data and store it into a file. I am aware that I cannot write to the assets dir or any other place because of the sole nature of the APK file.

I am wondering, if I create a file with something like:

```
FileOutputStream fileout = openFileOutput("text.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
OutputStreamWriter outputWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fileout);
outputWriter.write("write this string to file.");
outputWriter.close();
```

Since I cannot write any files to assets or any raw dir, where it will be written?

What will the location of that file be? Where will it be located in the Android file system ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Since I cannot write any files to assets or any raw dir, where it will be written?

`openFileOutput()` writes to [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html).

> What will the location of that file be? Where will it be located in the Android file system ?

That can vary by device and user. It will be to the same directory that is returned via a call to `getFilesDir()`.

Comment: Will this data be persistent ? Will this data be present as longs as my application is installed? I suppose it will be deleted if the user deletes local data or cache...

Comment: @AdrianIvasku: "Will this data be persistent ?" -- yes. "Will this data be present as longs as my application is installed?" -- yes, or until you change or delete the data, or until the user goes into Settings and clears the data for your app. That latter scenario is as if the user uninstalls and reinstalls your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the path to your file created with openFileOutput like this: `MainActivity.this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/text.txt"` and you can read it using an object of FileInputStream `FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(MainActivity.this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/text.txt"));`