# Android : Downloading the HTML file from server and save it into assets folder

Tags: android, webview, assets

I want to host an HTML file on server and once user is registered on the app, i want to get this file downloaded and saved into assets folder of the app on the local device and once i have this file into assets folder, i will display it into a WebView and user should be able to see the contents of that file every time user opens it.

And whenever i update the file on server, i want to display a popup for user to accept it, and once user have accepted it, i want to replace the old HTML file from assets folder with the new one.

And from now onwards, the new file will be downloaded on the local system and every time user wants to access the file, he should be able to access the new one.

I'm not sure if that's possible at all, but would certainly be interested in hearing from anyone that knows anything about such things.

Answer (score 0):

> Since I cannot write any files to assets or any raw dir, where it will
>   be written?

`openFileOutput()` writes to `internal storage.`

> What will the location of that file be? Where will it be located in
>   the Android file system ?
>
> The apk is read only and the assets/ folder is not modifiable at
>   runtime, which sounds like something you may be seeking.

[Link Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35524662/android-write-file-to-assets-folder)